# How to integrate object items in array convert to a table

Tags: javascript, php, arraylist, foreach

Could you please give me suggestion to solve this problem?

i got a datas like:

```
 orders =[
        {
            orderID:1,
            Name: 'Sam',
            orderList: [
                {SKU: 'A001',Qty: 2},{SKU: 'A003',Qty: 4}
            ]
        },
        {
            orderID:2,
            Name: 'Sam',
            orderList: [
                {SKU: 'A001',Qty: 1},{SKU: 'A002',Qty: 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            orderID:3,
            Name: 'Sam',
            orderList: [
                {SKU: 'A001',Qty: 2},{SKU: 'A004',Qty: 2}
            ]
        },
        {
            orderID:4,
            Name: 'Sam',
            orderList: [
                {SKU: 'A003',Qty: 3},{SKU: 'A002',Qty: 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            orderID:5,
            Name: 'Sam',
            orderList: [
                {SKU: 'A002',Qty: 1},{SKU: 'A003',Qty: 1}
            ]
        }
]
```

//after foreach i want to output each order items and gather their SKU and qty like:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
   echo <td>$order.orderList.sku</td>
   echo <td>$order.orderList.qty</td>
   
//output a table like:
/*
item     |    Qty
A001     |    5
A002     |    4
A003     |    8
A004     |    2
B001     |    1
/*
}
```

Please give me some suggestion, thank you so much!

Comment: For sorting PHP array you have many functions like `asort`, `usort` etc...